# Svelte: Promise { <pending> } Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Hello someone know why i have this error please?

**Promise {  }
Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined**

```js
<script>
    import { getProduct } from '../lib/store';
    const productId = 'a';
    
    const product =   getProduct(productId);
    $: console.log(product);

    let quantity = 0;
    let price = 0;
    let total = 0;
    $: quantity = quantity < 1 ? 1 : quantity;

    $: options = product.variants.edges.map((items) => {
        let list = {};
        list.id = items.node.id;
        list.color = items.node.selectedOptions[0].value;
        list.size = items.node.selectedOptions[1].value;
        list.price = items.node.priceV2.amount;
        return list;
    });

    $: console.log(options);
</script>
```

Datas comes from Shopify API
Thank you!

Comment: try using await on `getProduct(id)`

Comment: I have to put it in a function ?

Answer (score 3):

You are awaiting a promise from the getProduct call, so you need a place for the *results* of that promise to land, and then you can use them. You are seeing the error because you are trying to access the property `variants` of a promise, which doesn't exist, so JS give back undefined as would be expected. Then you try to access `edges` of undefined and get the error.

One way you can fix this is to do the following:

1. Expose product as a mutable variable, and set initial value to null:

```js
let product = null;
```

2. import the `onMount` method from svelte, and you can use it to run an async method, and await the promise for getProducts, then assign it to the product variable:

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte'

.....

onMount(async () => {
  products = await getProduct(id);
});
```

3. Set up your reactive variables to conditionally use product if it's not null:

```js
$:options = product ?  product.variants.edges.map((items) => {
        let list = {};
        list.id = items.node.id;
        list.color = items.node.selectedOptions[0].value;
        list.size = items.node.selectedOptions[1].value;
        list.price = items.node.priceV2.amount;
        return list;
    }) : null;
```

4. Only render markup that relies on options if it's present.

```
{#if options}
  /* Markup here dependent on options */
{/if}
```

Now the reactive `options` variable will update automatically when `product` is reassigned from `onMount`, and data and rendering will flow accordingly.

You could possibly use optional chaining instead of the ternary operator that I used, however until `product` is reassigned, `options` would be undefined instead of null. It's up to you on which to use and both ways will work, but I like to be more explicit with null instead of trusting the compiler to come up with the undefined value.